# Have to click twice for selecting tabpage c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a TabControl that has two TabPages.  Inside the first I have a propertygrid, and inside the second one I have a datagridview.  I fill both elements when I click one treeview list element outside the TabControl.

Everything works great, but when I click the second TabPage, I keep seeing the first TabPage contents.  I have to click the first TabPage, and the the second one again for finally seeing the second TabPage content.

What could be the problem?

Thank you all!

Comment: Got Some Code to Share?

Comment: Got any events on those Tabs?

Comment: I did not really know wich code I can submit, because I don't have any code that changes any property from neither the TabControl nor the TabPages.  I don't use any events on those Tabs, thats the really odd part.

The TabControl was created inside the design tab and every TabPage content is filled the same way.  I only fill de textbox, the propertygrid and the datagridview by code.

Comment: I see that if I click the second TagPage BEFORE getting the data from the mysql database I don't get this behaviour.  But if I click the second TabPage after getting the data from the mysql database I have to: Click 2nd TagPage, click 1st TagPage and the click 2nd TagPage in order to see the datagridview.  From that moment, I can switch between tabpages and I see them correctly.  But when I do another query to the database I have to repeat the process described to see the 2nd TabPage content.  Could be something focus related?